# Django - calling attribute from queryset with a string

Tags: python, django, class, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to loop over different query sets while not repeating myself too much and have encountered a problem using the queryset class.
This is not necessarily completely a Django-problem.

What I'm trying to do is to use my keylist, which corresponds to a django model's column names, to create a list of the data from those column names, what i want to do is something like this:

```
if needthisdata==1:
    needdata=['column1', 'column2', 'column3']
else:
    needdata=['column1', 'column4', 'column7']
entry=djangomodel.get.all().filter(identifier='id')
dictitems=[]
for n in range(0, len(needdata)):
    if n==0:
        dictitems=[entry.needdata[n]]
    else:
        dictitems.append(entry.needdata[n])
```

Which of course doesn't work since the queryset doesn't have a need data attribute, is there some way to call an attribute for a class with a string in this way?

Comment: Shouldn't this be `identifier`, instead of `itentifier`?

Comment: You can by the way use `getattr`, but a more efficient approach exists.

Comment: Furthermore here `entry` is a queryset (that can in theory contain *multiple* elements).

Comment: Fixed itentifier, @WillemVanOnsem, it is a queryset containing multiple elements, but instead of writing the foor-loops i have in my actual code i compressed it a bit, the syntax came out a bit weird because of that. gona test your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A valid Django statement to obtain a *single* entry

First of all, there are some semantical problems here:

- `itentifier` should probably be `identifier`, `id`, or `pk`;
- you use `.all` immedately instead of first obtaining a manager (probably `.objects`); and
- you here use a `.filter(..)` on the queryset to filter on an identifier, but usually this should be a `.get(..)`, since by using a filter, zero, one or more results can be returned in an iterable.

```
entry = djangomodel.objects.get(id=some_id)
```

So now we obtain a single entry, but that of course does *not* resolve 
obtaining the columns.

## If all elements are *real* Django columns

In case the columns are real Django fields (so no `@property`s, etc.) then we can use `values_list`, and perform a `list(..)` constructor on it:

```
dictitems = list(djangomodel.objects.values_list(*needdata).get(id=some_id))
```

## If case some elements are `@property`s

In case *not* all those fields are real Django fields, then we can use `attrgetter` instead:

```
from operator import attrgetter

dictitems = list(attrgetter(*needdata)(djangomodel.objects.get(id=some_id)))
```

Comment: Both solutions worked, and when used on a queryset with multiple matches i get a list with indices i can loop over. Perfect solution for my problem!